# Set item checked in onItemClick /ListView /

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I have Activity with ListView and buttons - "clear all" and "OK".
On button "clear all" I clear checked state of items - it works fine.

```
m_list.setItemChecked(pos, false);
```

On onItemClick I'm trying to change state of items/checked <-> unchecked/ depending on complicated business logic. Bussines layer decides checked 
or not for more than one item. I'm trying same code:

```
m_list.setItemChecked(position, bCheck);
```

It is not working. Data behind is changed only view not.

"Clear all" code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v == m_map)
        GoToMap();
    else if (v == m_clear)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < m_poiCategories.size();i++)
        m_list.setItemChecked(pos, false);
    }
}
```

This code not working:

```
m_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View selectedItem, int position, long itemId)
    {
        boolean b = true;
        ....
        m_list.setItemChecked(position, b);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with `ListView`s than it is required that `notifyDataSetChanged()` to be called from the UI thread when any data is changed. This will update the UI by calling `getView()` several times, depending how many items are displayed.

Make sure your `getView()` is properly implemented.

For reference I highly recommend to view and understand: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70